# Hive column data in array

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with data at hour level. I want to find the count of hours and the values for all hours in an array.
Input Table

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| hour| col1| col2|
+-----+-----+-----+
| 00  | 0.0 | a   |
| 04  | 0.1 | b   |
| 08  | 0.2 | c   |
| 12  | 0.0 | d   |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

As suggested in the below solution I am using function to get the column values in an array

```
select count(hr), 
       map_values(str_to_map(concat_ws(
         ',', 
         collect_set(
           concat_ws(':', reflect('java.util.UUID','randomUUID'), cast(col1 as string))
         )
       ))) as col1_arr,
       map_values(str_to_map(concat_ws(
         ',', 
         collect_set(
           concat_ws(':',reflect('java.util.UUID','randomUUID'), cast(col12 as string))
         )
       ))) as col2_arr from table;
```

Output that i am getting, values in col2_arr are not in the same sequence with col1_arr. Please suggest how can i get the values in array/list for different columns in same sequence.

```
+----------+-----------------+----------+
| count(hr)| col1_arr        | col2_arr | 
+----------+-----------------+----------+
| 4        | 0.0,0.1,0.2,0.0 | b,a,c,d  | 
+----------+----------------+-----------+
```

Required output:

```
+----------+-----------------+----------+
| count(hr)| col1_arr        | col2_arr | 
+----------+-----------------+----------+
| 4        | 0.0,0.1,0.2,0.0 | a,b,c,d  | 
+----------+----------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with    t as 
        (   
            select  inline
                    (
                        array
                        (
                            struct('00',0.0)
                           ,struct('04',0.1)
                           ,struct('08',0.2)
                           ,struct('12',0.0)
                        )
                    ) as (hour,col1)
        )

select  count(*),collect_list(col1),max(col1)
from    t
;
```

---

```
+-----+-------------------+-----+
| _c0 |        _c1        | _c2 |
+-----+-------------------+-----+
|   4 | [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.0] | 0.2 |
+-----+-------------------+-----+
```

If you want to guarantee the order of the elements within the array, use -

```
sort_array(collect_list(col1))
```

If you want to eliminate duplicates of the elements within the array, use -

```
collect_set(col1)
```

---

**Keeping duplicate values without collect_list**

```
with    t as 
        (   
            select  inline
                    (
                        array
                        (
                            struct('00',0.0)
                           ,struct('04',0.0)
                           ,struct('08',0.1)
                           ,struct('12',0.1)
                        )
                    ) as (hour,col1)
        )

select  map_values(str_to_map(concat_ws(',',collect_set(concat_ws(':',reflect('java.util.UUID','randomUUID'),cast(col1 as string))))))
from    t
;
```

---

```
["0.0","0.0","0.1","0.1"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I want to keep the duplicate values but collect_list is not available in hive 0.10.
Any other option to keep the duplicate values in list for hive 0.10 ?

I have tried collect_set which is eliminating my duplicate values.

Comment: I have an idea but it will have to wait for tomorrow (note to self: reflect + concat + collect_set + concat_ws + str_to_map + map_values)

Comment: See updated answer, and remember - you've asked for it :-)